# IE css how to?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, css

Im struggling with this for the past 3 months!! - how to adapt css3 to IE7,8 and 9??

this is my page

I am using buttons there, I want to make rounded corners (basic, no?)
so I have used this css

```
body .main_title {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0.3em 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #222222;
  color: white;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

and the button is

```
<button type="submit" id="1" class="main_title">מאפיינים</button>
```

as you noticed, I also used an "extention" called css3pie to make it work but nothing!!

any suggestion?

Comment: There is no such thing as `-ms-border-radius` or `-o-border-radius`.

Comment: Make sure the `.htc` file is in the same folder with the html file being viewed. I've tested your style in IE8 and it works.

Comment: hi , those settings came from compass sass (if you've heard).

Comment: it's strange to see that the buttons load fine in you IE8. do you know of a reason why?

Answer (score 3):

> any suggestion?

Sit back. Relax. Don't worry about minor cosmetic details in old browsers with falling marketshare.

Comment: While I do agree, sometimes these seemingly minor details are very important to the client. When this happens, the developer simply needs to comply.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 pie is kind of buggy. Try putting a `position:relative;` on it. Also make sure that's the correct path to PIE.htc — if I remember correctly, it may help to link to it absolutely.

Comment: thanks. tried.. it didn't work... I think the best solution is to wait it out....

Answer (score 0):

I think you can probably use jquery for this http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/ in your javascript.

Anything from IE9 onwards will be ok with this in the css

```
border-radius:10px
```

http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius